# Force Django to recognize multiple "models" folders in the same app?

Tags: python, django

My Django project is laid out strangely:

```
/project
    |----manage.py
    |----/project
        |----settings.py
        |----urls.py
    |----/main
        |----/users
            |----/models
                |----__init__.py
                |----model1.py
                |----model2.py
                |----model3.py
            |----/views
                |----__init__.py
                |----view1.py
                |----view2.py
            |----/forms
                |----__init__.py
                |----form1.py
                |---form2.py
            |----urls.py
        |----/activities
            |----/models
                |----__init__.py
                |----model1.py
                |----model3.py
            |----/views
                |----__init__.py
                |----view1.py
                |----view2.py
            |----/forms
                |----__init__.py
                |----form1.py
            |----urls.py
        |----/migrations
        |----urls.py
        |----admin.py
        |----apps.py
```

This is *almost* a normal setup—except `users` and `activities` aren't technically apps.; `main` is the app. My goal is to keep all migrations linear.

When I run `python manage.py`, Django sees the models in `main/users/models` but not in `main/activities/models`.

Is there a way of forcing Django to look in both folders when considering its migrations. I could create `models` folder w/ `__init__.py` that imports everything in `main`, but, if possible, I'd like to keep my current setup and just change where Django looks.

Comment: Make sure the submodules are imported in the `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems you'll need to overcome in this case.

1. There is no setting to get Django to look for modules in a module other than `models`. In fact, it's a hard-coded module name.
2. Even if you could override the module that Django it looking for, it's still only looking in a single module, and you have two.

You have a few options to make this work. First, I would strongly consider breaking this one app into two. You say that `users` and `activities` aren't apps, but their structures scream otherwise: not only do they each have their own `models`, they have their own `views`, `forms`, and `urls`. You'll end up with a much better structure if you make them their own, full-fledged apps.

If you'd really rather keep the existing structure, then you have two options. The easiest is to simply create a `main/models.py` and import your respective models from there.

**main/models.py**

```
from .users.models import *
from .activities.models import *
```

Simple as that. The more complicated option is to override the `.get_models()` and `.get_model()` methods in your `AppConfig` class in `main/apps.py`. I can come up with an exmaple of this if you want to go this route.

Comment: Importing from `__init__.py` doesn't actually work (I received an `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. 
` error). I'd prefer to do this, but adding `models.py` isn't a big deal. I think, for now, I'll keep this structure—it'll be pretty easy to send `users` and `activities` to their own apps if need be (I'm explicitly naming their data tables, so that shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will remove that suggestion.